# Something incomprehensible to the class

Tags: python, class, oop, import, python-class

Something incomprehensible to the class.

```
   From aiogram.types import InputFile
   
   a = InputFile(r'C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\f\1.mp3')
   b = InputFile(r'C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\f\2.mp3')
   c = InputFile(r'C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\f\3.mp3')
   d = InputFile(r'C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\f\4.mp3')
   e = InputFile(r'C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\f\5.mp3')
   
   class Make:
       def __init__(self, art, zanr, name, put):
       self.art = art
       self.zanr = zanr
       self.name = name
       self.put = put
   
   a1 = Make('Blaze', 'Hip-hop', 'Music_1234', a)
   b1 = Make('PORCHY', 'Rap', 'Trak_28', b)
   c1 = Make('Blaze', 'Pop', 'North-abc', c)
   d1 = Make('PORCHY', 'Hip-hop', '26-83', d)
   e1 = Make('Blaze', 'Pop', 'Abnov', e)
   
   spis = [a1, b1, c1, d1, e1]
   
   for x in range(0, 4):
       if spis[x].art == 'PORCHY':
           print(cl.spis[x].put)
```

Consol:

```
<InputFile 'attach://GqEaqV-Wj3zekeFP9GIygA' with file='<_io.BufferedReader name='C:\\Users\\Acer\\Desktop\\f\\2.mp3'>'>
<InputFile 'attach://JeYgSuIUgVjS7nDwPONivQ' with file='<_io.BufferedReader name='C:\\Users\\Acer\\Desktop\\f\\4.mp3'>'>
```

Why not it:

C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\f\2.mp3
C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\f\4.mp3

Comment: If you are referring to the doubled backslash, this is likely the result of `str.__repr__` being used via `BufferedReader.__repr__` to produce a *representation* of the file name.

Comment: no, why doesn't it just return the value of the variable "a"
in the format: C: \ Users \ Acer \ Desktop \ f \ 2.mp3. How to make it return like this?

Comment: Because the `put` attribute is an `InputFile` instance, not just a file name. You'd have to look at the definition of `InputFile` to see why its `__str__` method (or possibly `__repr__` method) is defined the way it is.

Comment: Put another way, it *is* showing the value of the variable `a`; that value just isn't a `str` object.

Answer (score 0):

By taking a look at  at the [InputFile source code](https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/_modules/aiogram/types/input_file.html) you can see that the `__str__` method is defined like:

```
def __str__(self):
        return f"<InputFile 'attach://{self.attachment_key}' with file='{self.file}'>"
```

and the `__repr__` method is equal to the `__str__`.

If you'd like to print only the path to the file, I believe you should be using

```
print(cl.spis[x].put.get_filename())
```

Comment: Thanks, but the console outputs like this:
2.mp3
4.mp3
And I need it like this:
C: \Users \Acer\Desktop\f\2.mp3
C: \Users\Acer\Desktop\f\4.mp3
I tried to write like this:
print (r'C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\f\ '+ cl.spis [x] .put.get_filename ())
Python considers cl.spis [x] .put.get_filename to be text and displays an error, can you tell me how to fix it?

Comment: try `print(os.path.realpath( cl.spis[x].put.get_file().name) )` after importing os

Comment: Thanks again, but here again the problem, this path to the file is passed to the bot, and it sends it to the user, I tried it like this:
`a = os.path.realpath (cl.spis [x] .put.get_file (). name)
print (os.path.realpath (cl.spis [x] .put.get_file (). name))
await bot.send_audio (chat_id = id, audio = a)`
So:
`print (os.path.realpath (cl.spis [x] .put.get_file (). name))
await bot.send_audio (chat_id = id, audio = os.path.realpath (cl.spis [x] .put.get_file (). name))`
But here's the error: